# Chart.js - Data Input as Array of Arrays

Tags: chart.js

Inputting data as follows works:

```
[
    {
        x: 1,
        y: 2
    },
    {
        x: 2,
        y: 3
    },
]
```

Depending on the data-source it needs some conversion though. In my use case I already have the data in RAM as follows:

```
[
    [1,2],
    [2,3]
]
```

As I am speaking about >500k data points, the loop for formatting the data is very expensive. I do it with a `map`-function right now.

```
var plotData = myArray.map(function (value) {
    return {
        x: value[0],
        y: value[1]
    };
});
```

Is there any possibility to pass the data as is (array of arrays)? I can't find any hint in the docs.

How it currently works:

https://jsfiddle.net/txugfcnd/

Comment: please create fiddle.

Comment: Added fiddle to post

Comment: So, you want two lines which the first line has 1,2 and the second one 2,3 ??

Comment: I think you did not get my problem. It should be one line from (1|2) to (2|3) as you can see it. But I dont want to pass the data as array of objects (additional loop required) but as array of arrays

Comment: still not clear,sorry. can you give the image that you are looking for/

Comment: The image is the same. It's just how you input data is structured.